# Unable to add Forgot Password link in Django Admin suit?

Tags: django

[image]
In my admin site, I have installed a Django suit and here I am trying to add forgot password link but can't add it Before installing the Django suit I added forgot password link and it was working perfectly but after installing suit it's not working. do you have any idea ??

login.html:

```
    {% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
    {% load i18n static %}
    {% block content %}

    <form action="{{ app_path }}" method="post" id="login-form">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-row">
        {{ form.username.errors }}
        {{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        {{ form.password.errors }}
        {{ form.password.label_tag }} {{ form.password }}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
      </div>
      {% url 'admin_password_reset' as password_reset_url %}
      {% if password_reset_url %}
      <div class="password-reset-link">
        <a href="{{ password_reset_url }}">{% trans 'Forgotten your password or username?' %}</a>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
        <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot password?</a>
      <div class="submit-row">
        <label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}">
      </div>
    </form>

    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the error message?